# SQL server select distinct latest values by inner joining three or more table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In my data base I have these tables each and every table has nearly 200,000 rows in it.

**User table:**

```
╔════════╦══════╦═════════════╗
║ UserID ║ Name ║    Email    ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════════╣
║   1    ║ ABC  ║ abc@abc.com ║
║   2    ║ DEF  ║ def@def.com ║
║   3    ║ XYZ  ║ xyz@xyz.com ║
╚════════╩══════╩═════════════╝
```

**Vacancy table:**

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╗
║ VacancyId  ║ VacancyName ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║     1      ║  Vacancy 1  ║
║     2      ║  Vacancy 2  ║
║     3      ║  Vacancy 3  ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**Vacancy Application table:**

```
╔══════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ VacancyApplicationID ║ VacancyId ║   UserID     ║ Application Date ║
╠══════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║           1          ║     1     ║      1       ║   2009-01-01     ║
║           2          ║     1     ║      2       ║   2009-01-02     ║
║           3          ║     2     ║      1       ║   2010-01-02     ║
║           4          ║     3     ║      1       ║   2011-02-02     ║
║           5          ║     2     ║      2       ║   2010-03-04     ║
║           6          ║     1     ║      3       ║   2009-04-07     ║
╚══════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

I am trying to combine some of the data together. I want to obtain the distinct user id and their latest applied vacancy in one grid, like this:

**Expected result:**

```
╔════════╦══════╦═════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ UserID ║ Name ║    Email    ║ Last applied vacancy ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║   1    ║ ABC  ║ abc@abc.com ║      Vacancy 3       ║
║   2    ║ DEF  ║ def@def.com ║      Vacancy 2       ║
║   3    ║ XYZ  ║ xyz@xyz.com ║      Vacancy 1       ║
╚════════╩══════╩═════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Now some of the users did not apply for any vacancy. For them I just want to put "N/A" in the last applied vacancy column. How can I do that?

I have tried using the SQL statement below, but it duplicates same user id data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.[id],
    va.[candidateid],
    va.[vacancyid] 
FROM user C 
INNER JOIN VacancyApplication VA ON c.userid=va.userid
ORDER BY va.application_date DESC
```

Comment: instead of giving in images why can't you give them as Sample data .It's completely additional work for us type all this data in our local machine

Comment: i tried.. ... the datas brokes... can't insert a table format...  :-(

Comment: Which do you actually have, MySQL or SQL Server?  These are two very different products.  This is a trivial variation on a classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query.  It includes a subquery on the vacancy application table to restrict to the most recent vacancy for each user.  In addition, it uses `COALESCE()` on the application date in the event that a given user does not have any applications.

```
SELECT u.UserID, u.Name, u.Email, COALESCE(v.VacancyName, 'NA') AS `Last applied vacancy`
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT UserID, MAX(ApplicationDate) AS maxDate
    FROM vacancy_application
    GROUP BY UserID
) v1
    ON u.UserID = v1.UserID
LEFT JOIN vacancy_application v2
    ON u.UserID = v2.UserID AND v2.ApplicationDate = v1.maxDate
LEFT JOIN Vacancy v
    ON v2.VacancyId = v.VacancyId
```

**Click the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: hi ... it does not give the vacancy name.. only gives vacancy id

Comment: I just checked the Fiddle and confirmed that it does give the vacancy name.  If you want the ID then just select `v.VacancyId` instead of the name.

Comment: sorry that was my mistake. thanks the query working.. but one little thing.. it only gives the user rows who have applied for any vacancy. the users who has not applied they are not in the record. if i just put one more record in the fiddle   (4, 'PQRS', 'pqrs@pqrs.com'); then this user is not in the result. as it has not record in the vacancy_application table.

Comment: @Bashabi I have updated my query and Fiddle and both are working now without error.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
   SELECT
  U.UserID,
  U.Name,
  U.Email,
  V.VacancyName
FROM User AS U
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
     UserID,
     MAX(ApplicationDate) AS MaxApplicationDate
FROM vacancyapplication AS VA
GROUP BY UserID
) AS MaxApp
ON U.UserID=VA.UserID
LEFT JOIN vacancyapplication AS VA
ON MaxApp.UserID=VA.UserID
AND MaxApp.MaxApplicationDate=VA.ApplicationDate
LEFT JOIN Vacancy AS V
ON VA.VacancyID=V.VacancyID
```

Comment: Hi thanks thats  working.. but it only gives the user rows who have applied for any vacancy. the users who has not applied they are not in the record. I just want to put n/a in the latest applied vacancy column for the users who has not applied for vacancy. How can I do that..  I have 112000 users. and i get  65000 number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for add the users without vacancy

```
SELECT c.[id] 
         , case when va.[candidateid] is null then 'N/A'
           else va.[candidateid]
           END as candidateid
         , case when va.[vacancyid] is null then 'N/A'
           else va.[vacancyid]
           end 
FROM  user  C LEFT OUTER JOIN VacancyApplication VA on c.userid=va.userid  
ORDER BY va.application_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
        select U.UserId,U.Name,U.Email,COALESCE(V.VacancyName, 'N/A') AS LASTAPPLIEDVACANCY from 
    (select USerId, VacancyId, max(Application Date) over(partition by userID)  from VacancyApplication) AS VA 
join Vacancy AS V on
        VA.VacancyId=V.VacancyId join User AS U on VA.UserId=U.UserID
```